# How can I configure my node package so I can load sources without specifying the src directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a Node package with this basic structure :

```
./my-package
  ./src
    ./index.js
    ./a.js
    ./b.js
  README.md
  package.json
```

In my `package.json`, I have `"main": "./src/index.js"` and the module loads fine. However, when I try to import a specific JavaScript file, I need to specify the full path relative to the package.

```
import a from 'my-package';        // OK
import b from 'my-package/b';      // NOT FOUND
import b from 'my-package/src/b';  // OK
```

Is there a solution so the `src` directory is used without requiring to specify it when importing?

Answer (score 0):

In the root directory of your package `my-package` create an index.js file and export everything you would want to have direct access to.

Example `index.js`:

```
import a from './src/a';
import b from './src/b';

module.exports.a = a;
module.exports.b = b;
```

Comment: But... if I do that, I will load every sources of my package and force loading stuff that may not be required. Is this really the only option??